# elasticsearch_dsl response multiple bucket aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

found this thread on how to frame nested aggregations using elasticsearch_dsl [Generate multiple buckets in aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346959/elasticsearch-dsl-generate-multiple-buckets-in-aggregation)

can someone show how to iterate through the response to get the second bucket results?

```
for i in s.aggregations.clients.buckets.num_servers.buckets:
```

does not work, how else to get to the content in num_servers or server_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops if you want to loop through an second level aggregation.  Here is an example assuming 'label' and 'number' fields in your index:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, A

client = Elasticsearch()

# Build a two level aggregation
my_agg = A('terms', field='label')
my_agg.bucket('number', A('terms', field='number'))

# Build and submit the query
s = Search(using=client, index="stackoverflow")
s.aggs.bucket('label', my_agg)

response = s.execute()

# Loop through the first level of the aggregation
for label_bucket in response.aggregations.label.buckets:
    print "Label: {}, {}".format(label_bucket.key, label_bucket.doc_count)

    # Loop through the 2nd level of the aggregation
    for number_bucket in label_bucket.number.buckets:
        print "  Number: {}, {}".format(number_bucket.key, number_bucket.doc_count)
```

Which would print something like this:

```
Label: A, 3
  Number: 2, 2
  Number: 1, 1
Label: B, 3
  Number: 3, 2
  Number: 1, 1
```